# Double click to edit question or answer

Tags: feature-request, edits

A number of forums have a neat feature which allows you to double click on the text to bring up the edit box and places your cursor immediately where you clicked.

This is instead of clicking the edit link at the bottom.

Can this be implemented?

To be clear, I'd really only want this implemented for editing my own posts.

Comment: If you have some extremely well-working example of *"and places your cursor immediately where you clicked"* then *maybe* Balpha is interested [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156656/position-cursor-at-approximate-area-while-clicking-on-preview/165197#165197).

Comment: [That would interfere with the select-word behavior of double click on my mac and with the select-sentence behavior of triple click.](http://xkcd.com/1172/)

Comment: If you really want this for yourself, just write a user script. It wouldn't be too hard to at least make a double click enter edit mode.

Comment: @dmckee it's the select word behavior of Windows too. And I think (effectively) of Android/iOS if I'm not mistaken

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I would say for most users the majority of time using Stack Overflow is not to edit.

And bringing this feature will result in a lot of false opening the editor for posts that one only wanted to view or scroll, especially on tablets.